# Error while trying to access Hive tables using Jdbc

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I need to write an API to get the data from Hive table so that I can process it so,I am trying to access Hive tables using Jdbc  .
A simple "Select * from table" works fine but "Select count(*) from table is throwing an error :

```
2017-04-20 18:05:57,709 INFO  [main] jdbc.Utils (Utils.java:parseURL(310)) - Supplied authorities: 10.94.154.125:10000
2017-04-20 18:05:57,712 INFO  [main] jdbc.Utils (Utils.java:parseURL(397)) - Resolved authority: 10.94.154.125:10000
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2017-04-20 18:05:57,790 INFO  [main] jdbc.HiveConnection (HiveConnection.java:openTransport(203)) - Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://10.94.154.125:10000/CloudData
Running: select count(*) from  ipticket
java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:296)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:392)
    at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:35)
```

Code :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/CloudData", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "table1";
  String  sql = "select count(*) from  " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    try{
         ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
         while (res.next()) {
              System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2)+"\t"+res.getString(3) + "\t" + res.getString(4));
            }

    }catch (SQLException f){
        f.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Side tip : [HivePreparedStatement](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/jdbc/HivePreparedStatement.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because Select count(*) launches a MapReduce job, maybe you have issues on your config files
try to test a map reduce job on your cluster
execute this
and change hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.*.*.jar with the jar version of your mapreduce exemples (if you have hadoop 2.6 it will look like /hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar)

> cd $HADOOP_HOME
>   then
>   hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.*.*.jar pi 2 5

if you had errors then MR is not configured to work correctly

Comment: No , the query works fine in the hive cli and I am able to see the result.So i confirm the problem is not with config files of MR

Comment: Issue solved with  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/CloudData", "usename", "password");